# Show next date (LEAD) based on simple condition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with a unique index on Contracts of Customers that live in Houses, I want to know how many days it takes for a House to be inhabited by the next person.

I am already quite far, but unfortunately my dataset has contracts with TYPE = 0, which are automatically generated by the system and which should be ignored,
if I don't ignore these 'empty contracts' with TYPE = 0, then the data says actually ALL houses are inhabited within 1 day.

Now I currently get the following result:

```
SELECT
CONTRACTID
,RENTALOBJECTID
,TYPE
,VALIDFROM
,VALIDTO
,LEAD(CONTRACTID) OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID ORDER BY VALIDFROM) AS 'NextContractId'
,LEAD(VALIDFROM)  OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID ORDER BY VALIDFROM) AS 'NextValidFrom'
,LEAD(VALIDTO)    OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID ORDER BY VALIDFROM) AS 'NextValidTo'
FROMPMCCONTRACT
```

With the following code:

```
CONTRACTID  RENTALOBJECTID  TYPE    VALIDFROM   VALIDTO     NextContractId  NextValidFrom   NextValidTo
HC001       1               0       1/1/2015    1/1/2017    HC002           1/2/2017        8/1/2017
HC002       1               0       1/2/2017    8/1/2017    HC003           8/2/2017        NULL
HC003       1               3       8/2/2017    NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL
```

However I want the result to look like the following, where it ignores the Contracts where TYPE = 0.

```
CONTRACTID  RENTALOBJECTID  TYPE    VALIDFROM   VALIDTO     NextContractId  NextValidFrom   NextValidTo
HC001       1               3       1/1/2015    1/1/2017    HC003           8/2/2017        NULL
HC002       1               0       1/2/2017    8/1/2017    NULL            NULL            NULL
HC003       1               3       8/2/2017    NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL
```

And as you can see the time in days for RENTALOBJECTID = 1 to be inhabited again after CONTRACT = HC001 is more than a month now.

Does anyone know how this works in SQL-server-2012?

Kind regards,

Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data is somewhat inconsistent and you have omitted to explain some aspects of the desired results but this should basically do what you need.

The window frame is set with `VALIDFROM` ordered descending and thus `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` includes all rows with higher `VALIDFROM`. Only ones with `TYPE <> 0` get a not null `ConcatResult` and the `MIN` picks out the one with the lowest `VALIDFROM` in that window frame (i.e. next biggest to current row). The three concatenated column values are then pulled out of this result.

```
WITH PMC
     AS (SELECT CONTRACTID,
                RENTALOBJECTID,
                TYPE,
                VALIDFROM,
                VALIDTO,
                ConcatResult = MIN(CASE
                                     WHEN TYPE <> 0
                                       THEN FORMAT(VALIDFROM, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                                            + FORMAT(ISNULL(VALIDTO, '1900-01-01'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                                            + CONTRACTID
                                   END)
                                 OVER (
                                   PARTITION BY RENTALOBJECTID
                                   ORDER BY VALIDFROM DESC 
                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
         FROM   PMCCONTRACT)
SELECT *,
       NextContractId = SUBSTRING(ConcatResult, 21, 10),
       NextValidFrom = CAST(SUBSTRING(ConcatResult, 1, 10) AS DATE),
       NextValidTo = CAST(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(ConcatResult, 11, 10), '1900-01-01') AS DATE)
FROM   PMC
ORDER  BY RENTALOBJECTID,
          VALIDFROM
```